# Why does this script not affect anything in the scene when I run it on Godot?

Tags: c#, game-engine, godot

```
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class PlayerCharacter : Sprite2D
{
    private Vector2 velocity = Vector2.Zero;
    private float movingSpeed = 100;
    private float maxSpeed = 500;

    // Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
    public override void _Ready()
    {
            GD.Print("Processing...");
    }
    // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
    public   void _PhysicsProcess(float delta)
    {
            GD.Print("Processing...");

        if (Input.IsActionPressed("left_move"))
        {        
            GD.Print("Moving left...");

            velocity.X += -movingSpeed;
        }
        else if (Input.IsActionPressed("right_move"))
        {
            velocity.X += movingSpeed;
        }
        else if (Input.IsActionPressed("jump"))
        {
            velocity.Y += movingSpeed;
        }
        else if (Input.IsActionPressed("down"))
        {
            velocity.Y -= movingSpeed;
        }
        else {
            velocity.X = 0;
            velocity.Y = 0;
        }
        if(velocity.LengthSquared() > (maxSpeed * maxSpeed) )
        {
            velocity = velocity.Normalized() * maxSpeed ;//keeps same direction but caps the maxspeed
        }
        
        Position += velocity * delta;


    }
}
```

This is the code for movement of my Sprite2D node

However when I tried to run it ,nothing ran,not even the debugging texts,leading me to suggest that the script is not attached to the node properly somehow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR6am.png)

This is the hierachy of my nodes

Comment: While I'd argue the code for movement belongs on the physics body, I would have expected this code to do something (I would have expected it to do the wrong thing in a very deceptive way). But you say it does nothing. I do not know why that could be.